# Correct order of connect.js middlewares?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

> middleware depend on each other, for example methodOverride() checks
>   req.body.method for the HTTP method override, however bodyParser()
>   parses the request body and populates req.body. Another example of
>   this is cookie parsing and session support, we must first use()
>   cookieParser() followed by session()_.

I wonder how can we know which middleware should be use before another? I wonder if there already exist an ordered list (a list with all middlewares in correct working order) somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of middleware on connect's [home page](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) is in the correct order, though it doesn't explicitly call out dependencies.

Comment: This is not the case. This answer is 15 months old so things may have changed. But, for instance, the home page lists `csrf` before `session` and `cookieParser`, when the csrf documentation clearly states: "This middleware requires session support, thus should be added somewhere below session() and cookieParser()."